# Highlight duplicate rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to highlight duplicate rows in several dataframes and export them to excel after. It seems to work when I do it with one dataframe, but as soon as I apply it to another dataframe is highlights the index from the last dataframe for all of them.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

colA = list(range(1,6))
colB = ['aa', 'bb', 'aa', 'cc', 'aa']
colC = [14,3,14,9,12]
colD = [108, 2001, 152, 696, 696]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(colA, colB, colC, colD)), columns =['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD']) 
print(df)

colA = list(range(1,7))
colB = [208, np.nan ,201, 150, 900, 670]
colC = ['aa', np.nan ,'bb', 'aa', 'cc', 'bb']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(colA, colB, colC)), columns =['colA', 'colB', 'colC'])
print(df2) 

def highlight_yellow(x):
    return ['background-color: yellow' if x.name in rows else '' for i in x]

row_series = df['colB'].dropna(how = 'any').duplicated(keep = False)
rows = row_series[row_series].index.values
df = df.style.apply(highlight_yellow, axis = 1)

row_series = df2['colC'].dropna(how = 'any').duplicated(keep = False)
rows = row_series[row_series].index.values
df2 = df2.style.apply(highlight_yellow, axis = 1)
```

When I just run the highlight function on the first dataframe it produces the correct results
[image]

But when I run it on both dataframes it overrides the correct result in the first dataframe, and highlights the same rows in the first and second dataframe instead.

[image]

The end result should look like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't you do `df[rows].style.apply`?  It's uncomfortable that you're relying on a global here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
def highlight_yellow(df, cols):
    style = 'background-color: yellow'
    a = np.broadcast_to(np.where(df.duplicated(subset=cols), style, '')[:,None], df.shape)
    return pd.DataFrame(a, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)   

df.style.apply(highlight_yellow, cols=['colB'], axis=None)
```

output:

[image]

```
df2.style.apply(highlight_yellow, cols=['colC'], axis=None)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `dropna` method first removes the rows with `nan` which affects the rows. You should do it separately something like below:

```
row_series = df2['colC'].duplicated(keep = False)
row_series[df2['colC'].isna()] = False
```